# Match multiple specific position

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression like this

```
/^((.{0}1.*)|(.{1}2.*)|(.{2}3.*)|(.{3}4.*))$/g
```

And this match each string that contains almost one digit in the same position of 1234.

Now i'm trying to build a regex that matches almost n digit in the same position of 1234. It is not important which digit matches, but that n digit matches. So using an AND operator will not help here. 
An idea is to build a regex that matches each charater in the right position and then in my python code i would write something like:

```
n_matches = len(re.findall(regex, val))
if n_matches == matches_to_hit:
    ...
```

But i'm stuck here to.. any idea?

**UPDATE**

I have 2 string in inputs. They are always a 4 digit string. Digit range is 0-9 and all digits are different. For example:

- 123 NOT VALID
- 1234 VALID
- 9874 VALID
- 1231 NOT VALID
- 12345 NOT VALID

I have to check if input A and Input B have n digits in the same position

So an example:

- Input A = 9837
- Input B = 1234

So if n is 1 then the regex should return a metch. If n > 1 no, because only the digit 3 is in the same position in input A and Input B.

Comment: Could you provide input data and wanted result?

Comment: check out square brackets in regexes. `[1234]{5}` matches one of 1 2 3 or 4 for n = 5.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i have updated my question. Hope it is more clear

Comment: @ParitoshSingh i have to mathc in a specific position, and not just if the string contains the digits

Comment: indeed, and you know how to match one of something in a specific location, so can you apply your existing knowledge and improve upon it? @FabioPiunti `teach a man to fish, as they say`

Comment: Is it necessary to use regex? It's pretty simple task to do on python.

Comment: looking at the question edit, this isn't a task for regex.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i know that this is a easy task in python, but i want to work more on regex to improve my knowledge about it

Comment: @ParitoshSingh neither a regex that match just the chars and not the whole string? I could then check how many matches there are and compare it to n. Like i have showed in the question

Comment: Since you only have nine digits, it's easy to expand your existing regular expression from four to nine digits. Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your use of word "almost" is confusing.
Do you need to match only strings which have digits as first 4 characters and all with all digits different?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your answer 100% correctly, but I understood it as: Write a regex matching a string "with exactly 4 digits as first 4 characters, all of which are different and no other digits present in a string"

This could be achieved with negative lookahead and back-references (and groups). The regex goes on as follows:

So we should have a digit `\d`. Then another digit `\d`, which is not the same as the first [match] `(?!\1)`. Then another digit `\d`, which is not the same as both previous matches `(?!(\1|\2))` and so on.

Here's the full regex with whitespaces added for readability:

```
/^
  (\d)
  (?!\1)(\d)
  (?!(\1|\2))(\d)
  (?!(\1|\2|\3))(\d)
  \D*
  $
/x
```

If you need to make it match whole string and some certain positions, you can remove `^`/`$` and sprinkle `\D` (not a digit) with quantifiers like `*`, `+` of `{10}` as necessary.

PS: I suggest reading this site https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and after reading all of it and some practice (by the way answering questions here on StackOverflow is a good way to practice) you'll become a regular expression guru, I promise you.

PPS: In real project I would implement that w/o regexes at all.

```
digits = [c for c in str if c.isdigit()]
return len(digits) == 4 and len(set(digits)) == 4
```